# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, avaudioplayer, nserror, ipad-mini

So this code runs fine on the iOS Simulators, but not on my iPad Mini

```
    var sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"/Users/Dan/Documents/XCode Code/Colors- Tabbed?/Colors- Tabbed?/Sweg.aiff")
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, error: &error)
    var error: NSError?
```

I get the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `AVAudioPlayer` hasn't been audited yet. It returns an implicitly unwrapped optional, which can be `nil`, and apparently *is* on your iPad. (Likely because your iPad doesn't know where `/Users/Dan/Documents/...` is, since that's on your computer.)

You want to capture the player in an optional value so you can test for `nil` before you use it:

```
var sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"/Users/Dan/Documents/XCode Code/Colors- Tabbed?/Colors- Tabbed?/Sweg.aiff")
var error: NSError?
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer? = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, error: &error)

if let audioPlayer = audioPlayer {
    // do things with the audioPlayer
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, do you know how I could put that file in my actual app so my iPad can find it? If so would I call it the same way?