# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know how to fix the "nil" that this error message is telling me.

My code:

```
var error:NSError?
self.player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL( string:"http://192.168.0.101:3000/output.mp3" ), error: &error)
```

I get the message:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)`

Comment: What is the type of `self.player`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value with AVAudioPlayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094651/unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value-with-avaudioplayer)

Comment: declared as AVAudioPlayer

Answer (score 0):

The initializer for AVAudioPlayer is declared as:

```
init!(contentsOfURL url: NSURL!,
         error outError: NSErrorPointer)
```

which, because of the `!` type specifier, means that a `nil` value can be returned.  Furthermore, the documentation implies that a `nil` will be returned if the URL does not reference a valid audio resources: "The audio data must be in a format supported by Core Audio. For a list of supported formats, see Using Audio in Multimedia Programming Guide."

As for your error, if you declare `player` as `AVAudioPlayer` (without a `?` type specifier), then when a `nil` is actually returned, you'll get your error/fatal.

```
 27> class Foo { 
 28.     var player : AVAudioPlayer 
 29.     init () { 
 30.         self.player = AVAudioPlayer (contentsOfURL: url, error: &error) 
 31.     } 
 32. } 
 33> Foo()
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Execution interrupted. Enter Swift code to recover and continue.
Enter LLDB commands to investigate (type :help for assistance.)
```

To 'fix' the problem, declare `player` as:

```
var player : AVAudioPlayer!
```

and in `init()` ensure that `AVAudioPlayer(...)` does not return `nil` before assigning to `player`.